# Selecting a jpg image with regex and golang

Tags: regex, go, xpath

I have an example of matching a jpg file with regex and golang.

[Regex sample](https://regex101.com/r/Wjp30B/1)

It selects it perfectly but does the opposite of what I want, it removes it instead of keeping it.

How do I get it to be the substitution as currently you will see it removes the jpg link and leaves the rest where I want the opposite of it only leaving the jpg link.

This is used in an xpath scraper where I want it to pass over just the jpg link.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `FindStringSubmatch` [1]:

```
package main
import "regexp"

const (
s = "background-color:#000000; background-image:url(https://www.sample.com/free-videos/player-images/20170204-01.jpg); background-size: cover; position: relative;"
)

func main() {
   a := regexp.MustCompile(`\(([^)]+)\)`).FindStringSubmatch(s)
   t := a[1]
   println(t == "https://www.sample.com/free-videos/player-images/20170204-01.jpg")
}
```

However, in real code, make sure to test `len(a)`. This is a pretty common task, so if you're interested, a module `xurls` [2] is available as well.

1. https://golang.org/pkg/regexp#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch
2. https://pkg.go.dev/mvdan.cc/xurls/v2

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```golang
.*?(https?:\/\/\S*\.jpg).*
```

Replace with `$1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xA8dQV/1).

*Details*:

- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(https?://\S*\.jpg)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `http`, an optional `s`, `://`, zero or more non-whitespace chars, and then a `.jpg` substring
- `.*`  - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible